# Selecting only 2 names by regex

Tags: regex, perl

Input is John Doe, desired output is Doe, John. Bad input is John Smith Doe

my code is

```
    if ($input =~ m/([A-Z][a-z]*)\s([A-Z][a-z]*)$/){
    print "$2, $1";
}
```

It works fine with John Doe, but when John Smith Doe entered, I want to display an error message but my code displays Doe, Smith. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, you need to use the match the beginning of the line metacharacter (`^`):

```
if ($input =~ /^([A-Z][a-z]*)\s([A-Z][a-z]*)$/){
    print "$2, $1";
}
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions

Comment: Perfect! I appreciate the help!

Comment: @ValeriaKaya No problem, also note that `*` will match zero or more times. That means that `M J` will be matches, if you use `+` it will match one or more times, also take a look at `{n,m}`

Comment: @ValeriaKaya It's always nice to help people who do an effert before asking :-)

Comment: it is also nice to get help from nice people instead of the ones saying ""go read the manual" ;)

Comment: @ValeriaKaya Well technically I said you should read the manual ;-)

Comment: I like how you welcome the OP the way you do. I've noticed that SO can be rough at times, so it's nice to see a warming intro. ++. Kudos.

Comment: I mean the ones just being rude and saying things like "go read the manual before asking", "learn a little bit of coding before trying this", such and such

Comment: Stack Overflow is a little rough, because it is about helping programmers with their programming problems. It gets a steady flow of people who are looking to just outsource their day job, or are otherwise being too lazy to ask for free help effectively. You will get good answers - even to trivial problems - if you show some effort before you ask. If it _looks_ like you're just being lazy, you won't get a lot of tolerance.